# Why does fit_transform change my p-values for linear regression with Gram-Schmidt

Tags: correlation, p-value, least-squares

I am running some OLS regression on correlated IV's. I use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to transform to a new set of uncorrelated (orthogonal) variables. I then check for the importance of each IV using a t-test and associated p-value for each regression coefficient.

The p-values/significance I get for my regression change depending on if I center/scale (using StandarScaler().fit_transform() in python) the IV's before the G-S process. Why is this the case? And which p-values should I regard as correct?

Comment: Are you transforming the dependent variable as well?

Comment: Linear regression coefficients are not scale-invariant, so rescaling *should* change your slopes. Your p-values changing is not surprising.

Comment: @Galen Thanks for your reply. I'm not transforming the dependent variable. Which p-values are "more accurate" & what does it mean for them to change under a transform? If a p-value is say <0.05 before the transformation but significantly > 0.05 afterwards what is this saying about my independent variable? In theory my p-value tests to see if the slope is 0

Comment: In what sense are you thinking about p-values being more or less accurate?

Comment: If I set alpha = 0.05, then if p<0.05 in one case I interpret the IV as statistically significant and if p>0.05 I interpret it as statistically insignificant. So if my p-value changes  on transformation my interpretation is changing - but which interpretation is correct?

Comment: What these p-values say about your predictors is an estimated probability of estimating a parameter as extreme as you did. This is always done under some distributional assumptions or sometimes through resampling. The change in p-value due to transformation suggests that rescaling the variables leads to slopes with a higher estimated probability of being whatever they were assuming a t-distribution.

Comment: If your goal is feature engineering, an often-better approach for predictive models is to perform hyperparameter tuning where choices of transformations are hyperparameters. You should use an extra set of data to perform the selection, rather than on the training data.

Comment: My impression was that the p-value tells me something about the coefficient being zero/non-zero (the lower the p-value the more probable the coefficient is non-zero). Is this incorrect!? My goal is to figure out which IV's are statistically significant to the linear regression i.e. f(x)=a x1+b x2 + c x3 ... but if for e.g. c = 0 then the model can be reduced

Comment: re p-value~non-zero: Yeah, that isn't entirely accurate. It is more like a probability of estimating a slope as far out on the tails of the (t-)distributions as what you estimated.

Comment: I think if you are trying to select the most predictive model that you should drop using these null hypothesis significance tests and instead train multiple models and compare which performs the best on predicting test data.

Comment: Since you mentioned Python, I might add that I have gotten pretty good mileage out of [Optuna](https://optuna.org/).